# Native module cannot be null

Tags: ios, react-native

[image]

On running the react- native app for iOS, the emulator opened up with this screen. On searching for the problem, I found that there were no solutions to it provided by people, please help.

Earlier, i got a problem that the simulator was not even loading, and the build was failing with this error:

The following build commands failed:

```
CompileC /Users/mi0205/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTWebSocket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTWebSocket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTSRWebSocket.o RCTSRWebSocket.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
/Users/mi0205/AwesomeProject/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
  throw err;
```

On reading a bit, I came to know that deleting the RCTWebSocket scode project file will lead to successful build, so I did that, but this problem came up thereafter

Comment: The 2nd error is quite obvious - dev tools require RCTWebSocket module to be present and throw because it's missing. You should add it back. After that, open up Xcode, clean project, run it again and in case it fails, please paste in here the entire stack trace (or build log). If it's too long, `gist` is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message after trying to use fetch. Took my a while to realize that I needed the 'RCTNetwork' pod added to the subspecs in my Podfile:

```
target 'MyProject' do
    # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
    # use_frameworks!

    # Pods for MyProject
          pod 'React', :path => '../my-project/node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
          'Core',
          'RCTText',
          'RCTNetwork',
          'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
          # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
     ]
end
```

More information here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html